# exec.Command setting output stream not getting all data

Tags: go, io

This works

```
res = exec.Command(gitCmd, cmdArgs...)
res.Stdout, res.Stderr = os.Stdout,os.Stderr
```

When executing a git command like `git clone ..` you get full syntax response like

```
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), done.
```

BUT if you wrap it in a multiwriter like this

```
res = exec.Command(gitCmd, cmdArgs...)
res.Stdout, res.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout),io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr)
```

You lose all the resolving / receiving outputs, that you normally see. 
Why ?

The following works but to me seems unnecessary, IMHO the io.MultiWriter should do the same ...

```
res = exec.Command(gitCmd, cmdArgs...)
res.Stdout, res.Stderr = os.Stdout,os.Stderr
stdout, stderr = new(bytes.Buffer), new(bytes.Buffer)
go io.Copy(os.Stdout,stdout)
go io.Copy(os.Stderr,stderr)
```

Comment: `git` probably checks to see if it's standard error "[`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)" before printing out that extra information. The reason for this is because it "prints" the `\r` character to jump to the beginning of the line to update the percentages, etc.. This behaviour would not be desirable if the output file was anything but a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the TTY. Using a MultiWriter (or anything else) would break the TTY. If you want to do so, you need to use a PTY master/slave pair. You can take a look at https://github.com/kr/pty for more info.

Comment: That makes sense, the work around (using the go io.Copy) works well enough in this instance as it does not have to be an accurate history. I just wanted to show some activity and the io.MultiWriter gave me nothing. Appreciate the answer and the link..